# Subsite to be manage by only Site Owner

Tags: permissions, master-page, access, access-denied, customization

Is it possible to customize the subsite to exclude site collection administrators and system accounts from accessing it?

One thing I have tried to do is to have a check via jsom in the masterpage and it works. However, user can bypass this method by halting the loading of the page before the jsom even executed.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It defeats the purpose of SCA

Comment: One of our departments does not want any other users, including IT, to have access to the subsite due to confidentiality of items.

Comment: Then how are you going to manage the site if something goes wrong? Second create a different site collection all together.

Comment: I think it won't be the case where in only one subsite will go wrong, most likely it would affect the entire site collection. Similar to my reply to Eric's answer, creating a new site collection is still accessible to the same farm account. I would not go for creating a separate farm for this.

Answer (score 0):

No, that cannot be done. If that is a requirement, then the subsite should be created as it's own site collection.

Comment: This approach would still grant access to the farm account right? Is there other way to prevent it?

Comment: The farm account will have access too, there will be no way around that, high privileged accounts will always have access to everything.

Comment: Yes that is true, which is why I am thinking if somebody has done a customization of some sort that will be able to check whenever the site is being accessed. Similar to the check on the masterpage without the loophole

Comment: that isn't true security as you've already noted. If it is that big of a concern, then turn on audit on the site collection, and you'll be able to run reports against anyone you think may have accessed the confidential information. There is no way to deny farm and admin accounts from having access, other than making sure the wrong people don't have those credentials to get in.